# Does opcache_reset via cli also resets apache opcache

Tags: php, apache, opcache

I have to implement functionality which will reset opcache via terminal.

This is my current configuration
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.enable_cli = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 12850
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
opcache.fast_shutdown = 1
```

/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini

```
[opcache]
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.enable_cli = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 256
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 12850
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
opcache.revalidate_freq = 0
opcache.fast_shutdown = 1
```

My question is, when i run some shell script, which will execute something similar to this php script `php -r "opcache_get_status();"` will this reset some "global" opcache or this will reset only cli opcache and you have to implement something else for apache.

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and will provide. Thank you!

Comment: IIRC, it only resets cli opcache... I had to set up a curl request to a web link to reset apache opcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Op_cache (for apache) needs to be reseted via url or curl request. It's not the same if you run `php -r "opcache_reset();"` via cli, meaning that op_cache on Apache won't be reseted. My solution was/is to create simple virtual host which is executing small php script for reseting op_cache.

my virtual host

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/opcache
    ServerName localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /var/www/html/opcache>
        Options All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
        Allow from localhost
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my php script

```
<?php
    opcache_reset();
```

And then i execute script with curl via terminal

```
curl -o -I -L -s -w "Response code %{http_code}\n" http://127.0.0.1/opcache/index.php
```